# How to add extra space to RecyclerView with clipToPadding=false to prevent premature recycling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

which is a simple RecyclerView below a SearchView. I want the RecyclerView's views to scroll behind the SearchView, so clipChildren and clipToPadding are set to false.
My problem is that RecyclerView is (rightly) recycling its adapter's views when they are still visible, just because they are out of the RecyclerView's area. Is there a way to add an extra space to the RecyclerView within which views are not recycled?

*EDIT, a gif showing the problem:*

## [image: the behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

This method should help you `setItemViewCacheSize(int size)`. It sets the number of offscreen views to retain before adding them to the potentially shared recycled view pool. More about it you can find [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: actually it does not work; the doc says what I would read, but actually the views disappear. Say I set size to 1, when the first view is out of the RecyclerView's area it disappears, probably it is not recycled, but surely it is not visible anymore...

Comment: Really strange. Would it be a big problem for you to put a gif or a link to video of that happening? Is it possible that some other view is covering the top of recycler?

Comment: And also you can turn of recycling by putting `recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(TYPE_MY_ITEM, 0);` where TYPE_MY_ITEM is type of view that you don't want to recycle. This way you can test is it problem with recycling or is it something else.

Comment: I added a gif with the result, the same with setItemViewCacheSize(size) called with 1, 2, or n

Comment: It looks like recycler is removing them. Try putting `recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(TYPE_‌​MY_ITEM, 20);` to 20 or some other big number. Thing is that your views are small and you have a lot of them on screen so they start recycling pretty early. I hope this will help, because I am out of ideas :).